# Can I dynamically create a class name and then use it to call static function of that class in PHP?

Tags: php, class, static-functions

I have two classes with the same static methods but each class has different implementation of the methods. In my code I know which static method I need to call, but the class type is determined dynamically. Something like this:

```
class someClass_A {
    public static function bar(){
        //some implementation;
    }
    public static function foo(){
        //some implementation;
    }
}

class someClass_B {
     public static function bar(){
        //different implementation;
    }
    public static function foo(){
        //different implementation;
    }
}
```

I am trying to use the in this manner:

```
$class = 'someClass_' . $indicator;
$bar = $class::bar();
```

But it's not working. Can I dynamically create a class name and then use it to call static function of that class?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) for this.

```
class someClass_A {
    public static function bar() {
        return "I am the A-bar";
    }
    public static function foo() {
        return "I am the A-foo";
    }
}

class someClass_B {
    public static function bar() {
        return "I am the B-bar";
    }
    public static function foo() {
        return "I am the B-foo";
    }
}

$indicator = 'A';
$class = 'someClass_' . $indicator;
$aBar = call_user_func_array(array($class, 'bar'), array());

$indicator = 'B';
$class = 'someClass_' . $indicator;
$bFoo = call_user_func_array(array($class, 'foo'), array());

echo $aBar, PHP_EOL;
echo $bFoo, PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
I am the A-bar
I am the B-foo
```

**Update**

Then again, your code ...

```
$class = 'someClass_' . $indicator;
$aBar = $class::bar();
```

... actually should be working as well. Just remember to set the `$indicator` variable before calling:

```
$indicator = 'A';
$class = 'someClass_' . $indicator;
$aBar = $class::bar();
echo $aBar, PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
I am the A-bar
```